# Using grep with RedHat 7.7

Tags: linux, grep, redhat

`ls *` output :

```
dossier_1:
vc.all.2019.09.17.Tue.gz  vc.all.2019.09.19.Thu.gz  vc.all.2019.09.21.Sat.gz  vc.all.2019.09.22.Sun.gz  vc.all.2019.09.24.Fri.gz
vc.all.2019.09.18.Wed.gz  vc.all.2019.09.20.Fri.gz  vc.all.2019.09.22.Sun     vc.all.2019.09.23.Mon     vc.all.2019.09.25.Wed.gz

dossier_2:
vc.all.2019.09.17.Tue.gz  vc.all.2019.09.18.Wed.gz  vc.all.2019.09.19.Thu.gz  vc.all.2019.09.20.Fri.gz  vc.all.2019.09.21.Sat.gz  vc.all.2019.09.22.Sun  vc.all.2019.09.22.Sun.gz  vc.all.2019.09.23.Mon

dossier_3:
vc.all.2019.09.17.Tue.gz  vc.all.2019.09.18.Wed.gz  vc.all.2019.09.19.Thu.gz  vc.all.2019.09.20.Fri.gz  vc.all.2019.09.21.Sat.gz  vc.all.2019.09.22.Sun  vc.all.2019.09.22.Sun.gz  vc.all.2019.09.23.Mon
```

If I do

```
ls * | grep -v "gz"
```

On my directory, I find :

```
dossier_1:
vc.all.2019.09.22.Sun
vc.all.2019.09.23.Mon

dossier_2:
vc.all.2019.09.22.Sun
vc.all.2019.09.23.Mon

dossier_3:
vc.all.2019.09.22.Sun
vc.all.2019.09.23.Mon
```

What is the command if I want this output :

```
dossier_1:
vc.all.2019.09.17.Tue.gz  
vc.all.2019.09.19.Thu.gz  
vc.all.2019.09.21.Sat.gz  
vc.all.2019.09.22.Sun.gz  
vc.all.2019.09.24.Fri.gz
vc.all.2019.09.18.Wed.gz 
vc.all.2019.09.20.Fri.gz  
vc.all.2019.09.25.Wed.gz


dossier_2:
vc.all.2019.09.17.Tue.gz  
vc.all.2019.09.19.Thu.gz  
vc.all.2019.09.21.Sat.gz  
vc.all.2019.09.22.Sun.gz  
vc.all.2019.09.24.Fri.gz
vc.all.2019.09.18.Wed.gz 
vc.all.2019.09.20.Fri.gz  
vc.all.2019.09.25.Wed.gz


dossier_3:
vc.all.2019.09.17.Tue.gz  
vc.all.2019.09.19.Thu.gz  
vc.all.2019.09.21.Sat.gz  
vc.all.2019.09.22.Sun.gz  
vc.all.2019.09.24.Fri.gz
vc.all.2019.09.18.Wed.gz 
vc.all.2019.09.20.Fri.gz  
vc.all.2019.09.25.Wed.gz
```

I want to display the name of the directory **and** his own files with only **.gz** extension.

But I don't know how to do this.

Can you help me ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using `awk`

```
ls -A1 * | awk '/(^|:|\.gz)$/'
dossier_1:
vc.all.2019.09.17.Tue.gz
vc.all.2019.09.18.Wed.gz
vc.all.2019.09.19.Thu.gz
vc.all.2019.09.20.Fri.gz
vc.all.2019.09.21.Sat.gz
vc.all.2019.09.22.Sun.gz
vc.all.2019.09.24.Fri.gz
vc.all.2019.09.25.Wed.gz

dossier_2:
vc.all.2019.09.17.Tue.gz
vc.all.2019.09.18.Wed.gz
vc.all.2019.09.19.Thu.gz
vc.all.2019.09.20.Fri.gz
vc.all.2019.09.21.Sat.gz
vc.all.2019.09.22.Sun.gz

dossier_3:
vc.all.2019.09.17.Tue.gz
vc.all.2019.09.18.Wed.gz
vc.all.2019.09.19.Thu.gz
vc.all.2019.09.20.Fri.gz
vc.all.2019.09.21.Sat.gz
vc.all.2019.09.22.Sun.gz
```

- `ls -A1 *` list all files (names only) in all folder, one line at the time
- `/(^|:|\.gz)$/` find all lines that are `empty`, ends with `:` or ends with `.gz` and print them.

Comment: Thank you ! It's exactly what I needed !

Answer (score 1):

`grep -v 'gz'` will exclude all input lines containing `gz`, so not sure why you used `-v` option when you actually wanted them to be preserved

I'd suggest a shell loop solution using globs

```
for d in *; do echo "$d"; ls -1 "$d"/*.gz; echo; done
```

- `for d in *` will loop over all the files/directories in current working directory. I'm assuming you only have directories
- `echo "$d"` will display the directory name

  - use `echo "$d:"` if you wish a colon character at end of directory name
- `ls -1 "$d"/*.gz` will display all files ending with `.gz` for this directory in single column
- `echo` to display an empty line

Comment: Thank you ! It's exactly what I needed !